# Android Sherlock ActionBar Remove Icon changed Menu Items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I have in my app Sherlock ActionBar and I remove app icon in actionbar by this code in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

But It changed padding of text in MenuItem.

[image]

I want set padding of the text to the left as before. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the actionbar title with the same space as if the icon was present?

Instead of using a transparent color as icon replacement, you could use an transparent drawable with the size of a normal actionbar icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<size android:width="32dp" android:height="32dp" />
</shape>
```

Use it in your style:

```
<item name="android:icon">@drawable/icon</item>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I want set text of MenuItem ("Autosalon Průhonice",..) to the left. I edited the picture. There is big space between left border menu and text (in red square) and I want remove that space. Do you understand me?

Comment: Could you please post your style.xml too?